How to authorize a Gmail account with Oauth to send verification emails with django-allauth
So from 2025 less secure apps are going to be disabled and i can't figure out how to integrate gmail account with django-allauth anymore in order to send verification emails. I have OAuth consent screen and credentials, Client_id, Client_secret but i don't understand how can I use this gmail account with django.
I know i lack code here, but literally didn't get anywhere other than creating an account in google console and activating OAuth/Credentials. Been searching for any guide online but they are all using less secure apps.
Tried something with https://docs.allauth.org/en/dev/socialaccount/providers/google.html but not even sure if this has anything to do with logging in an account into the app and sending emails using that account

Assuming you followed the allauth docs, added the app to INSTALLED_APPS and added its accounts/ url in your urlconfig, then it's now as simple as going into Django Admin and saving your Google OAuth id and secret. This is outlined in the doc you linked in your question.
After that, visiting /accounts/google/login in your browser (or whatever url you have configured it under) should initiate the OAuth flow.

Have you tried apps password

I also encountered an issue when trying to send email verifications. Specifically, you need a Gmail account that won't ends with @gmail.com. If you're using a different type of Gmail, such as a college or office email (e.g., charitra.shrestha@patancollege.edu.np), it may support less secure apps in its settings.
For accounts like these, you may need to enable App Passwords in the Gmail settings. If you'd like, I can provide my Gmail for testing purposes. Feel free to message me on Instagram (https://www.instagram.com/_charitraa_/), and I’ll share my Gmail to help you test the email verification process.
Alternatively, you can enable App Passwords on my another account and try it yourself. i have two account of my college.
Verification.

